# MediaWiki: Forcing new line in templates

Tags: mediawiki, template-engine

I'm going to standardize some picture galleries at some non-public wiki using pure templates. The legacy wiki picture/thumbnail galleries are specified with a lot of boilerplate code (it renders a gallery of pictures with thumbnails underneath):

```xml
<center>
<gallery widths="120px" heights="170px" perrow="5">
Image:Pic1.jpg|<center>1</center>
Image:Pic2.jpg|<center>2</center>
Image:Pic3.jpg|<center>3</center>
Image:Pic4.jpg|<center>4</center>
Image:Pic5.jpg|<center>5</center>
Image:Pic6.jpg|<center>6</center>
Image:Pic7.jpg|<center>7</center>
</gallery>
</center>
```

This is scary. There is an idea of re-implementing the above code with the following template:

```
{{Photos
| Picture1.jpg = 1
| Picture2.jpg = 2
| Picture3.jpg = 3
| Picture4.jpg = 4
| Picture5.jpg = 5
| Picture6.jpg = 6
| Picture7.jpg = 7
|}}
```

The template is mostly as follows:

```
... var definitions, etc ...
<center>
{{#tag:gallery
| {{#forargs: | K | V |
Image:{{#var: K}} {{!}} <center>'' {{#var: V}} ''</center>
}}
| widths = {{#var:WIDTHS}}
| heights = {{#var:HEIGHTS}}
| perrow = {{#var:PERROW}}
}}
</center>
```

But the problem is that only the first image is rendered, and the whole rest *Picture 2... Picture 7* is rendered under the first image thumbnail. And I suspect that the reason possibly is a missing new line character so the gallery tag may be rendered like this producing wrong 1-picture gallery:

```
<gallery widths="120px" heights="170px" perrow="5">
Image:Pic1.jpg|<center>1</center>Image:Pic2.jpg|<center>2</center>Image:Pic3.jpg|<center>3</center>...
```

It's only an assumption, but I guess it may have strong background. So the question is:
is there any way of forcing a new line break so the <gallery> tag could be rendered as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force a newline by adding `<nowiki />`like this:

```
{{#tag:gallery
| {{#forargs: | K | V |<nowiki />
Image:{{#var: K}} {{!}} <center>'' {{#var: V}} ''</center>
}}
| widths = {{#var:WIDTHS}}
| heights = {{#var:HEIGHTS}}
| perrow = {{#var:PERROW}}
}}
```

Comment: Just curious: how does it work? I can't see how a new line is related to the nowiki tag. Could you please make a little explanation? It would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I really don't know. It's an old hack, sometimes used in complex templates on Wikipedia. My guess is that it [stops wiki parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Wiki_markup#Nowiki), and then starts from scratch again after the tag. Thereby, the rule in the parser that removes linebreaks and other whitespace in templates is not applied.